# How to determine how many numbers lie between the max and min values from user input python

Tags: python, max, min

```
 for line in file:
    line = int(line)
    if line <= maximumValue:
        counter = counter + 1
    if line >= minimumValue:
        counter = counter + 1
    print (int(line))
file.close()
```

I am taking a file of a list of numbers, say from 1 to 10. I want to list the max and min values, as well as the values between the min and max. When I have my program open the file, it only prints out the total amount of numbers, and doesn't eliminate those that are higher then the max or lower then the min. What am I missing here and what can I do to correct it?

Comment: You are comparing string to numbers... `int(line)` should be the first thing in the loop

Comment: line = int(line) Like this? I already have this in the code.

Comment: Then you should post your real code. BTW, you are counting each value twice.

Comment: How can you have something > max and < min?

Comment: your question talks about values, not counts.  what do you really want?

Comment: I want to count the values in between.

Comment: you might want to edit your question so that it asks what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Python supports normal (readable) inequalities:

```
numbers = []
counter = 0

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        number = int(line)

        if minimumValue <= number <= maximumValue:
            numbers.append(number)
            counter += 1

print(counter)
print(numbers)
```

Also, use `with` to open files. You don't have to worry about closing them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

An example using a handy property of `xrange`:

```
MIN = 3
MAX = 7

valid_range = xrange(MIN, MAX+1)
with open('file') as fin:
    nums = (int(line) for line in fin)
    valid_vals = [num for num in nums if num in valid_range]
    # or if you just want count of valid values
    count = sum(1 for num in nums if num in valid_range)

print valid_vals, len(valid_vals)
```